# Creating a get_template_part() function like WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I like WordPress function get_template_part() where its basically a PHP file but doesn't use require_once, require, include etc. Basically it returns data to be stored in variable. Every WP function includes another function, its a loop and hard to find how actually it works. I created a small function but I dont know if it is the right way, or it will put a lot of load on system when everything will be using this function to load diffident PHP files as templates:

```
function get_template_part( $template ) {
    $path = dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'admin'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'templates'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if ( file_exists( $path . $template .'.php' ) ) {
        ob_start();
        require_once $path . $template .'.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else
        return "<strong>Template Missing:</strong> ".$template.".php";
}
```

Can someone please check of my above function is good to load all templates in a big system, if not please advise on how does WP does it or if you can please help upgrade my little function to avoid any potential problems. I also created another function, but still not satisfied (this function does not run <?php but only evaluates the variables..

```
function template($fname) 
{
    $tfile = TEMP_DIR."/$fname.tpl";
    if(!file_exists($tfile))
        return "<br /><b>warning</b> : missing template - $fname<br />";
    
    $data = file_get_contents($tfile);
    $data = str_replace("\"","\\\"",$data);
    
    return $data;
}   

function eval_template($tpl) 
{
    $tpl_data = template($tpl); 
    $arr = array(); 
    if( preg_match_all('/\$\w+/', $tpl_data, $matches) ) { 
        $arr = array_unique($matches[0]); 
        foreach($arr as $v) {
            $v = str_replace('$','',$v);
            global ${"$v"};
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "I like WordPress function get_template_part() where its basically a PHP file but doesn't use require_once, require, include, etc." - The function [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) calls [`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) which calls [`load_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/) which eventually calls `require`. Or am I misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: "is good to load all templates in a big system" What is not good using get_template_part() in big system ? Why reinventing the wheel ? You will use plugins that WILL use that anyway... adding more wont improve.

Comment: @Snuffy - thanks.. why because I dont want to use WordPress and not using it, will use this function in my own CMS..

Comment: @ChrisHaas - actually require and other such inclusion will print the data before the wanted placement, hence I am using ob_start() to assign data to variable and then print wherever needed..

Comment: I'm unclear if you have a problem or not, or if you are just asking for a code review?